# Set $_SERVER variable when calling PHP from command line?

Tags: php, email, pipe, command-line-interface

Is it possible to pass a `$_SERVER` variable to a PHP script via the command line?

Specifically I am trying to set the `$_SERVER['recipient']` manually so I can test email piping without setting up a mail server.

Comment: not a very clear question but perhaps you want: php script.php command_line_arguments_go_here

Answer (score 44):

On *nix:

```
$ recipient="email@example.com" php script.php

<?php

print_r($_SERVER);
```

Test:

```
$ recipient="email@example.com" php script.php | grep recipient

[recipient] => something@example.com
```

Or, you can export it or setenv (depending on your OS), like

```
$ export recipient="email@example.com"
$ setenv recipient="email@example.com"
```

Comment: Note that this is also useful for setting built-in variables such as $_SERVER['HOST_NAME']. Works like a charm!

Comment: Is there a reason this does not work for DOCUMENT_ROOT? Is there a way around that?

Comment: Is there a Windows alternative here?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with PHP 5.6? Oh--it works if you run php script.php, but not if you do php -S.

Comment: @JohnWiseman I'm disappointed just as you! :( see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67808

Answer (score 3):

**The answer by @sberry is correct.**

...but because I came to this page looking for setting **default values** for the `$_SERVER` array, when running PHP from command line, here is my own answer. Hope it might help somebody.

```
empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/';
empty( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ) && $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = __DIR__;
print_r( $_SERVER );
```

Comment: this was helpful for a GitHub action running CodeIgniter which was failing to pick up the path

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the following.

Example: set **$_SERVER['recipient]** in my PHP command line.

**With OS X**

- Follow the instructions in https://github.com/ersiner/osx-env-sync
- Append the following line to the file '**~/.bash_profile**' (create it, if it does not exist)

  `export recipient="something@example.com"`

**With Ubuntu GNU/Linux**

- Append the following line to the file '**/etc/environment**' (create it, if it does not exist, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

  `recipient=something@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass two and more variables. For example:

```
$ SERVER_NAME="example.com" REQUEST_URI="?foo=bar" php script.php

<?php

print_r($_SERVER);
```