# PHPUnit on Android Device

Tags: php, android, phpunit

I have built a pretty decent dev environment on my android tablet but one of the things I'd like to accomplish is to get PHPUnit to work on it so I can run unit tests from it.

I am using Palapa Web Server which comes with lighttpd 1.4.35 and php 5.5.15.

When I try to `php phpunit.phar --version` I get:

> Notice: Undefined index SCRIPT_NAME.

When I run a script from the command line the `$_SERVER` array is missing most indexes but when I run the same script from a browser they are present.

Comment: It seems to be mis-detecting the console environment as the server environment. As far as I know, it should not be trying to access `$_SERVER` at all on the console. I would be inclined to report it to the PHPUnit project, if I were you. Optionally, do some tracing to see if this is accessed on a desktop machine from the console.

Comment: Hi, Have you already see [this](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1255)? Hope this help

Comment: I have seen that link but unfortunately it doesn't really help. While I agree that the issue is not with PHPUnit itself I do think that the $_SERVER array is missing some indexes. I believe this has to do with using lighttpd and PHP as a CGI instead of an Apache module. My (hopefully) temporary workaround for now is that I have installed Debian linux on my tablet and can now run a full blown LAMP stack. This seems overkill though considering I really only need to use it for PHPUnit at this point. Atleast now I can run GIMP if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution via this SO question:

[Accessing $_SERVER variables from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287716/accessing-server-variables-from-command-line)

I had to use this command in the terminal:

```
SCRIPT_NAME=phpunit.php php phpunit.phar
```

I can now run PHPUnit on my Android tablet from the terminal emulator with no need to run Linux.